# Efficiently counting leaves in a tree stored in a db

Tags: python, sql, django, tree, graph-theory

I have a Django project that has two models: Group and Person. Groups can contain either Person objects or other Group objects. Groups cannot form a cycle (i.e. Group A containing Group B containing Group A), which results in a tree structure where Person objects are leaves.

My question is - how can I count all the contained Group objects and Person objects within a high level Group (like the root Group) with as few SQL queries as possible?

A naive approach with O(N) (where N is # of subgroups) SQL queries would be:

```
def Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    parent_group = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name=child_groups, null=True, blank=True)

    # returns tuple (# of subgroups, # of person objects)
    def count_objects(self):
        count = (self.child_groups.count(), self.people.count())
        for child_group in self.child_groups.all():
            # this adds tuples together ( e.g: (1,2) and (1,2) make (2,4) )
            tuple(map(operator.add, count, child_group.count_objects()))

def Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    picture = models.ImageSpecField(...)
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group', related_name="people")
```

Is there a way to improve this or should I just store these values within the Group object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is an existing problem that many others have tackled. If you're using Django, check this out:
http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/index.html

Comment: +1 for mptt, probably the best method to store trees for this sort of task.

Answer (score 0):

- Within Postgres you could use [recursive](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) queries, although there is no direct support for this in Django.
- Alternatively you could consider denormalising the count, possibly there are libraries to do this. A quick google gave me: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-composition/
- If you have to select the same values quite often and they don't change that much, you could try caching them.